# Create a Mechanical Turk HIT That Requires Multiple Workers

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I would like to create a job on Amazon Mechanical Turk that involves two workers engaging in a dialogue. I already have the javascript interface coded up. How would I manage two workers simultaneously, though? I don't want one worker to have to wait around for the second worker to join.

One workaround I was thinking about was having workers sign up for time slots, i.e. the 5 pm slot. Then the two workers signed up for the time slot could both join at the same time, without waiting around. Is this something I can do through Mechanical Turk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, you can use [JATOS](https://www.jatos.org/) for exactly this.